# How can I eliminate the extra 0 of microsecond in python datetime.datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I'm writing some code and I need compare two date that come from different source (API and DB) but I have some problem:

this is what the API and DB give me back:

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 5, 3, 0, 23, 30000)
b ='2016-08-05T03:00:23.3'
```

if I compare a == b I receive False so I'm trying to format the first value in this way:

```
a.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

the problem is that in the result I have a lot of extra 0:

```
'2016-08-05T03:00:23.30000'
```

in this case as well, if I compare a == b I receive False.

Is there some way to ignore all the trailing 0 in the microsecond?

Comment: it doesn't work, if I use .rstrip('0') my string become: '2016-08-05T03:00:23.03' that has a 0 in front of the 3 in the microsecond so the code still find difference between '2016-08-05T03:00:23.03' and '2016-08-05T03:00:23.3'

Comment: perhaps did you miss an extra 0 in `a`? `a = datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 5, 3, 0, 23, 300000)` because the last part is microseconds and `a` will as a result be 2016-08-05T03:00:23.030000 and will indeed not be equal to `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two are not the same; the `datetime` has 30,000 microseconds but the string has 300,000.

Instead of converting the `datetime` to a string, convert the string to a `datetime`.
This gives a more reliable comparison.

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 5, 3, 0, 23, 300000) # This should be equal
b ='2016-08-05T03:00:23.3'
c = datetime.datetime.strptime(b, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
if a == c:
    print "Equal"
else:
    print "Not equal"
```